# Stylesheet Blocked by Google after Rendering

Tags: css, magento, stylesheet, robots.txt

When rendering my website in Google Search Condole (Fetch as Google), I discovered that my site's stylesheets are blocked. The fetch status says "Partial". I suspect this reason for my site not showing up in Google Search results.

However, after adding my website to the Bing Search engine, it shows up in the search results after an hour. Hence, my website doesn't face any indexing issues in Bing.

How do I allow Googlebot to access my site's CSS files?

I am using Magento website. Here are the fetch details from Search Console:

```
http://www.cherryconcept.com/skin/frontend/default/ma_sahara_fashion5/css/styles.css3.php?url=http://www.cherryconcept.com/skin/frontend/default/ma_sahara_fashion5/    Style Sheet Blocked robots.txt Tester
http://www.cherryconcept.com/skin/frontend/default/ma_sahara_fashion5/css/bootstrap.css Style Sheet Blocked robots.txt Tester
http://www.cherryconcept.com/skin/frontend/default/ma_sahara_fashion5/css/bootstrap-theme.css   Style Sheet Blocked robots.txt Tester
http://www.cherryconcept.com/skin/frontend/default/ma_sahara_fashion5/css/font-awesome.css  Style Sheet Blocked robots.txt Tester
http://www.cherryconcept.com/skin/frontend/default/ma_sahara_fashion5/css/font-awesome.min.css  Style Sheet Blocked robots.txt Tester
http://www.cherryconcept.com/skin/frontend/default/ma_sahara_fashion5/css/styles.css    Style Sheet Blocked robots.txt Tester
http://www.cherryconcept.com/skin/frontend/base/default/css/widgets.css Style Sheet Blocked robots.txt Tester
http://www.cherryconcept.com/skin/frontend/default/ma_sahara_fashion5/magentothem/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css  Style Sheet Blocked robots.txt Tester
http://www.cherryconcept.com/skin/frontend/default/ma_sahara_fashion5/magentothem/ajaxcartsuper/ajax_cart_super.css Style Sheet Blocked robots.txt Tester
http://www.cherryconcept.com/skin/frontend/default/ma_sahara_fashion5/magentothem/css/categorytabsliders.css    Style Sheet Blocked robots.txt Tester
http://www.cherryconcept.com/skin/frontend/default/ma_sahara_fashion5/magentothem/css/custommenu.css    Style Sheet Blocked robots.txt Tester
http://www.cherryconcept.com/skin/frontend/default/ma_sahara_fashion5/magentothem/imagerotator/effect.css   Style Sheet Blocked robots.txt Tester
http://www.cherryconcept.com/skin/frontend/default/ma_sahara_fashion5/layerednavigationajax/jquery-ui.css   Style Sheet Blocked robots.txt Tester
http://www.cherryconcept.com/skin/frontend/default/ma_sahara_fashion5/magentothem/css/ma.upsellslider.css   Style Sheet Blocked robots.txt Tester
http://www.cherryconcept.com/skin/frontend/default/ma_sahara_fashion5/magentothem/css/ma.verticalmenu.css   Style Sheet Blocked robots.txt Tester
http://www.cherryconcept.com/skin/frontend/default/ma_sahara_fashion5/magentothem/css/ma.banner7.css    Style Sheet Blocked robots.txt Tester
http://www.cherryconcept.com/skin/frontend/default/ma_sahara_fashion5/magentothem/css/ma.brandslider.css    Style Sheet Blocked robots.txt Tester
http://www.cherryconcept.com/skin/frontend/default/ma_sahara_fashion5/css/print.css Style Sheet Blocked robots.txt Tester
http://www.cherryconcept.com/skin/frontend/default/ma_sahara_fashion5/images/logo.png   Image   Blocked robots.txt Tester
```

And here is my `robots.txt`:

```
# Google Image Crawler Setup
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow:

# Crawlers Setup

# Directories
Disallow: /404/
Disallow: /app/
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /downloader/
Disallow: /errors/
Disallow: /includes/
#Disallow: /js/
#Disallow: /lib/
Disallow: /magento/
#Disallow: /media/
Disallow: /pkginfo/
Disallow: /report/
Disallow: /scripts/
Disallow: /shell/
Disallow: /skin/
Disallow: /stats/
Disallow: /var/

# Paths (clean URLs)
Disallow: /index.php/
Disallow: /catalog/product_compare/
Disallow: /catalog/category/view/
Disallow: /catalog/product/view/
Disallow: /catalogsearch/
#Disallow: /checkout/
Disallow: /control/
Disallow: /contacts/
Disallow: /customer/
Disallow: /customize/
Disallow: /newsletter/
Disallow: /poll/
Disallow: /review/
Disallow: /sendfriend/
Disallow: /tag/
Disallow: /wishlist/
Disallow: /catalog/product/gallery/

# Files
Disallow: /cron.php
Disallow: /cron.sh
Disallow: /error_log
Disallow: /install.php
Disallow: /LICENSE.html
Disallow: /LICENSE.txt
Disallow: /LICENSE_AFL.txt
Disallow: /STATUS.txt

# Paths (no clean URLs)
Disallow: /*.php$
Disallow: /*?SID=
```

Answer (score 0):

The `robots.txt` you posted doesn't seem to be the one [you're currently using](http://www.cherryconcept.com/robots.txt). Your current `robots.txt` contains:

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Allow: /blocked-folder/css/
Allow: /blocked-folder/java/

...

Disallow: /skin/
```

So you're explicitly telling Googlebot not to fetch files in the `/skin` directory.

**Edit:** You also have the following rule

```
Disallow: /*.php$
```

which disallows all PHP files. Remove these lines and you'll be fine.

Comment: I changed /skin directory to Allow:/skin/ and render result still partial but I google found one issue;  
http://www.cherryconcept.com/skin/frontend/default/ma_sahara_fashion5/css/styles.css3.php?url=http://www.cherryconcept.com/skin/frontend/default/ma_sahara_fashion5/

Comment: I removed php lines and edit some php file to Allow, almost done for complate but still appear one issue;
syleesheet uncreachable
Also robots.txt found one warnings
craw-delay:10

Comment: Google doesn't use `crawl-delay` and will report it as a warning. The big search engines have also taken leadership from Google and have a Webmaster Tools type system where you can shape the crawling traffic through a 24 hour period instead of just slowing the crawl across the board.